# What should we do?

Tags: discussion

I found [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/why-did-neo-have-powers-in-the-real-world) related to [another question on Matrix trilogy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35/are-there-specific-plot-inconsistencies-in-the-matrix-trilogy?rq=1). In the first question, the inconsistency it is referring to, has been labelled as an inconsistency in the answers of 2nd question. Zhen and Barry Hammer s answer speak it is an **inconsistency**. However in the comments celtschk and System Down argued it is not. I think Alanannos answer to the first question rules out the possibility of this being an inconsistency.

So I think now we should delete Zhens answer to the 1st question and edit Barry s answer to the 1st question, otherwise viewers would get wrong information.

Also we can merge Alannanos answer instead to the 1st question arguing it not being an inconsistency.

Comment: What?....no.....

Comment: @TylerShads, why not? Users can get wrong information. :O

Comment: Users get wrong information all the time - even in real life. We do not set ourselves up as the authorities here - the community supports good answers through upvoting; downvoting others. The reader takes away what he wants, even if it is wrong. We're not a cult shaping weak minds.

Comment: Are you actually suggesting to delete existing and valid answers and merge others, just based on the opinion of other users? Think through it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break this down shall we?

> I found this question related to another question on Matrix trilogy. In the first question, the inconsistency it is referring to, has been labelled as an inconsistency in the answers of 2nd question. Zhen and Barry Hammer s answer speak it is an inconsistency. However in the comments celtschk and System Down argued it is not. I think Alanannos answer to the first question rules out the possibility of this being an inconsistency.

So a new answer to a new question has been provided on a question asked *the first day the site was out* on something that has similar subject matter.

Your opinion is that @Alennano's answer to this is correct (and personally, it does make the most sense in terms of the story).

> So I think now we should delete Zhens answer to the 1st question and edit Barry s answer to the 1st question, otherwise viewers would get wrong information.

First off, you are referencing one user's opinion (backed up by objective facts) and suggesting we should *delete* their answer based on that they *might* be wrong.

That goes against the point of **voting**.

Deletion should be reserved for answers that should be *comments and spam*.  Never for something that is *wrong*.  Even in the flagging system, there exists a reject option that states something along the lines of "Flags should not be used to point out incorrect answers".

If you disagree with an answer **Downvote**.

Just because something *new* has been pointed out on something *old*, doesn't mean we go around and deleting the older answers.  At that point, it rests on the **users** to downvote and comment to ask the person for an edit or a discussion in chat on why they believe their answer is right vs the new ideals.

It is not up to the mods to alter the content of the site just because a user might be wrong.  We are here merely to keep the peace, and promote executive decisions for the better of the site.  If someone is wrong, then that is the job of the community to disagree by downvoting, commenting why they believe the person is wrong, and/or inviting them to chat to discuss their different ideas.

Unlike a more objective site like SO, our site allows answers that could be perceived as *wrong* due to evidence viewed in a different light could produce different results.  That is why only the *OP* determines what they believe is the *right* answer.

> Also we can merge Alannanos answer instead to the 1st question arguing it not being an inconsistency.

This is impossible. If @Alennano wants to provide his own answer to the older question, then so be it.  The only thing we can do is merge the questions, which combines all answers, but the more and more I look at that older question, the more I want to close it as it looks more like a *opinion* question than anything else.

> @TylerShads, why not? Users can get wrong information. :O – Mistu4u 31 mins ago

As @wbogacz just stated while I was typing this up.  People get wrong information and spout it as right.  I assume people smarter than to believe the first thing they read on the INTERNET of all places.

Comment: This is a really good answer.Thanks for making it clear.

Comment: It should be noted that even on SO, a problem can also be solved by different coding language, structure, idea, etc.  Even there where things are more cut and dry, there is room for interpretation and debate.

Comment: I am amazed at the number of people that want to flag poor posts for moderators to deal with - when downvoting a bad or incorrect answer is the best way to get the community opinion.